# Design pattern for parsing text

Tags: parsing, design-patterns

I have a kind of logical problem. I have to write a program which should parse messages of different types.
Below I show an example how those messages look like:

```
MESS1

DATE=06.06.2016
CAR_MODEL=OPEL

#Total_Number3
#Max_HP123


MESS2

DATE=12.01.2016
CAR_MODEL=FORD

MARTIN/SMITH
JOHN/PUTIN


MESS3

DATE=13.12.2016
CAR_MODEL=BMW

1/3/4
```

I know its not a difficult to code in a simple way, but I would like to implement this using design patterns which allow me to easily modify it when
new type of message appears, some type of message changes or a message contains data in different order.

P.S I was thinking about Builder but messages does not contain the same fields so in my opinion it does not fit.

Greetings and thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused.  I see that the 3 message types have a date and a car model, but what does the additional information represent?

Comment: It's just an example. It does not mean what each message represt, the main meaning is that each message contains shared properties and additionally its own.

Comment: the idea of using a "small language" comes to mind, but i can not find any links for it :(

Comment: "small language" is also known as the Interpreter pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/interpreter

Answer (score 4):

According to your question, I assume that you have several MessageFormats which have some fields in common & some are not, and need a mechanism to parse each of them.

[Visitor](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) pattern is what you are absolutely looking for.

You can organize your classes as below. So different MessageFormats are the visitors here. They can be inherited from one common parent since they have some common attributes, And MessageParser is the care-taker who treats each visitor accordingly.

```java
public abstract class MessageFormat{
    private String commonField1;
    private String commonField2;

    // getters and setters.
}

public class MessageFormat1 extends MessageFormat{
    private String nonCommonField1;
    private String nonCommonField2;

    // getters and setters.
}
```

Like above you can define your different message formats MessageFormat2, MessageFormat3 etc. Now you should use [method overloading](http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java) to implement the methods of care-taker class (MessageParser) to complete the visitor pattern.

```java
public class MessageParser{
    public void parse(MessageFormat1 mf){
        // logic specific to MessageFormat1.
    }
    
    public void parse(MessageFormat2 mf){
        // logic specific to MessageFormat2.
    }
}
```

If you want to have some common logic for parsing common fields you can do something like below in MessageParser class.

```java
public class MessageParser{
    public void parse(MessageFormat1 mf){
        parse(mf); // calling private method.
        // logic specific to MessageFormat1.
    }
    
    private void parse(MessageFormat mf){
        // logic common to all MessageFormats.
    }
}
```

Note that the return-types I have mentioned should be adjusted according to your requirements.

Comment: Hi, thanks that is the pattern I was looking for. It would be perfect if there was a possibility to somehow not implement the same visior interfaces in every message  format.  What I mean. Lets assume we have 3 message formats with different fields where 2 of them can be managed by Lets say TaxVisitor but the third one does not have anything in common with taxes SO it wont be necessary to deffine a visit method for him is there any way to bypass that without lets say throwing not implemented exception?

Comment: @piess105 so isn't there any requirement to implement a visit method for 3rd one? Though it doesn't have any means of taxes, yet it needs a visit method right??

Comment: Good advice,  with little correction required. I believe "So different MessageFormats are the visitors here." is a wrong statement. Actually, MessageFormats are the element structure instances which are accepting visitors. Different MessageParsers which are supposed to implement a common visitor interface are good example of visitors.

Comment: Worth to mention, according to visitor pattern `MessageFormat` needs to have an `accept(Visitor visitor)` method. in our example it can be `accept(IParser parser)`

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late but I think the best design pattern for this problem is ***Interpretter***
you have an abstraction class ***Parser*** which have a **virtual function *parse*** and you create different class derived from Parser class that **override *parse* function** based on its feature

```
struct Parser {
   Parser( initargs) {

   }

   virtual void parse() {

   }
};

struct TaskParser:Parser {
   TaskParser(initargs):Parser(initargs) {

   }
   void parse() {

   }
};
```

the only thing you need to do is to read message header and based on that instantiate proper object file from your class

Comment: Dear, Interpreter design pattern is for building a language grammar, not for addressing parsing function and what you present here is not an interpreter.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern 
Check the part starting with "While the interpreter pattern does not address parsing,  a parser is provided for completeness." So, the parser itself is not a part of the interpreter pattern. Interpreter design pattern builds a language structure only, the other parsing direction is not a good example for interpreter.